# Why does this simple sum function fail to compile?

Tags: compile, summation, index

Consider the following compiled function, which takes a $12 \times 5$ array $x_{ij}$ of real numbers and computes the triple sum
$$ \sum_{k=1}^5 \sum_{i=1}^{12} \sum_{j=i+1}^{12} x_{ik} x_{jk}. $$

```
Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}},
    Sum[x[[i, k]]*x[[j, k]],
        {k, 5}, {i, 12}, {j, i + 1, 12}
    ]
]
```

When I attempt to evaluate this, *Mathematica 10.1* on Windows throws the following error at me:

> `Compile::cpintlt: i+1 at position 2 of x[[i+1,5]] should be either a nonzero integer or a vector of nonzero integers; evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>`

It looks like the indices of the `Sum[]` are being inserted before the expression is passed to `Compile[]`. Why does this happen? Note that if I re-index the sum as
$$ \sum_{k=1}^5 \sum_{i=1}^{12} \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} x_{ik} x_{jk} $$
*Mathematica* has no problem compiling the resulting function:

```
Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}},
    Sum[x[[i, k]]*x[[j, k]],
        {k, 5}, {i, 12}, {j, i-1}
    ]
]
```

This compiles just fine. Why does this version work, and not the previous version?

Comment: The original one also works if you convert the threefold sum into three nested sums. I believe you've encountered a bug, or at the least, a limitation of `Compile` (of which there are many).

Comment: @m_goldberg That isn't true. *Mathematica*'s default behavior in the case of an empty sum (lower index > upper index) is to return 0, even inside a `CompiledFunction`. You can try, for example `Sum[x[[i]], {i, 13, 12}]`.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to write the sums which contain combinations of indices that don't exist.  The first sum should have $i$ going from 1 to 11 rather than 1 to 12 and the second sum should have $i$ going from 2 to 12.  In addition for this example the sum can be greatly made more efficient (in terms of number of operations) to `(Sum[(Sum[x[[i, k]], {i, 12}])^2, {k, 5}] - Sum[x[[i, k]]^2, {k, 5}, {i, 12}])/2` or `(Total[Total[x]^2 - Total[x^2]])/2`.  This follows from expanding the square of the column sums.

Comment: @JimBaldwin You're absolutely right, and if I were actually using this code I would definitely adopt one of those simplifications. I used this only as an intentionally simplistic example to demonstrate a potentially buggy behavior I found.

Comment: The third argument of `Compile` might be what you need — e.g. `Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}}, Sum[x[[i, k]]*x[[j, k]], {k, 5}, {i, 12}, {j, i + 1, 12}], {{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}}]`.

Answer (score 6):

This seems rather be a error of determining the type of `i`, `j` and `k` than `Sum` itself. When you introduce your iterator variables in a `Module` and make clear that they are of type integer, it compiles fine for me:

```
fc = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}},
  Module[{i = 0, j = 0, k = 0}, 
   Sum[x[[i, k]]*x[[j, k]], {k, 5}, {i, 12}, {j, i + 1, 12}]]
]
```

Btw, I want to note that StephenLuttrell's solution of giving the type as last argument works too.